# If we treat the wave function as a vector, do we treat the wave function in 2d as a tensor?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, tensor-calculus, vectors

1D wave functions are elements of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and so do vectors. And we can switch between the two by promoting an index $i$ to a continuous variable $x$:

$$q^i \to \psi(x)$$

In 2D, there are two continuous variables $\psi(x,y)$. Do these variables get demoted to indices resulting in a rank 2 tensor?

$$\psi(x,y) \to q^{ij}$$

Comment: Wavefunctions are always vectors in the sense of belonging to the vector space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. They do not satisfy the geometric definition of a vector and it is only this definition which is related to the concept of a tensor.

Answer (score 1):

> In 2D, there are two continuous variables ψ(x,y). Do these variables get demoted to indices resulting in a rank 2 tensor?

The output of the wavefunction in more than one dimension is still just a single complex number at every point. The input, however, becomes (in 3d) three positional arguments and one time argument. If you have $N$ particles, the input is $3N$ positional arguments and one time argument. The output though is still a single complex number at each point.

If you model a particle with spin, then at each position you can assign a vector whose length depends on the maximal spin of the particle modeled. But this does not have to do with number of dimensions.